# .htaccess Error in Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter I have put an .htaccess in root folder of codeigniter 2.1.3.
I have tried my .htaccess file on both xampp & wamp server but this is not removing my index.php.
I have also set

```
 $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

and here is my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|images|system\/plugins|robots\.txt|css\/)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

i dont know why this is not removing my index.php page from url.
help me!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open config.php make sure to change $config['uri_protocol']= 'REQUEST_URI';

and in place this code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|indexcp\.php?|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/.-]+)$ index.php?/welcome/$1
```

That's all it works for me. Let me know if you are still facing any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether **rewrite_module** is configured as **on**

And try removing the condition from your code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|images|system\/plugins|robots\.txt|css\/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in my project it works for me,

.htaccess :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

config.php :-

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Another sily problem that could be done is that the folder that contains the application is not 755.

For be more sure about what is the problem look your apache log file , in linux /var/log/apache/error.log