# Codeigniter with index.php removed ready

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm looking for a codeigniter download with the index.php already disabled.

Are there any resources available for this? I have been trying to remove it the past week, and I have checked countless tutorials about the htaccess and config.php plus the apache modrewrite and allowoverride, but it still does not seem to work, so I'm looking if there is a downloadable resource which I can download and stop the hassle of configuring it.

Comment: Which index.php are you referring to. The index.php in the root directory is required for CI to run (front controller). Not clear as to what you want otherwise

Comment: Check this post it will help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049567/htaccess-error-in-codeigniter/14049813#14049813

Answer (score 2):

"the hassle of configuring it" is most likely due to something specific to your host; for example, there are special hoops you have to jump through to get it to work on GoDaddy

Other than that, there's nothing all that difficult - the "generic" configs work for 95% of the users. So what you want to do is post your specifics AND YOU HOST SERVICE on the Codeigniter forums or here, and someone with experience in that area can help guide you through.